# How do I build a react project for the browser using babel 6?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have set up a react porject that I am trying to build with the following command:

```
babel --presets es2015,react --watch src/ --out-dir lib/
```

Which does work and compile the jsx files into js and place it in `lib/`.

The problem is that babel transpiles stuff like:

```
import { Form } from "Form"
```

into

```
var _Form = require("Form");
```

Which the browser does not have a clue how to treat and hence I get a wonderful:

**TodosApp.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: You need to look into a bundler now, like Webpack or Browserify.  I personally find Webpack to be the more powerful of the two. https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack

Comment: Pete Hunt (one of the original React developers) did a good walkthrough of how to use Webpack here: https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Babel](http://babeljs.io) is responsible for transforming the code into stuff the browser can understand and run without syntax errors, but with no browsers supporting ES modules yet, the only options are to compile ES6 code into [CommonJS](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html) or [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd) modules.

We've got tools like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io) that work with CommonJS and it's the preferred format within the React ecosystem. It's also the default export type for Babel.

Then there's [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) which works with AMD type modules, but you'd have to use a different [Babel plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-amd/) to export AMD modules instead.

Once your code has been compiled to one of these formats you need a module bundler to start building up a dependency graph by looking at your entry file and recursively finding out which other files it requires, then concatenating them altogether into one big file that can be served as your application.

It's responsible for defining the `require` function and the `module` and `exports` objects and wrapping each of your modules in a function which will provide them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use browserify with babel. Here a link that explain [how it works](http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/)